# How can I select 20 values from MFCC?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mfcc

I'm Mathematica 11.3 user. To make a classifier for recognization of music instrument, I need MFCC values from music data set. I got data from IRMAS.
Length of music varies from 5sec to 20sec.

How can I get 20 values for input dataset in classifier?
Usually, I got {2389,13} Matrix.

How should I set parameters, like sample rate, window size, number of coefficients, target length, etc?

My code is

```
enc=NetEncoder["AudioMFCC"]
```

I want to know what those parameters mean.

Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/netencoder/AudioMFCC.html). Expand the "Details" section to see how to specify sample rate, window size etc. and what those parameters mean.